# Creating firewall excetption using netsh command

Tags: windows-firewall

I am trying to use netsh command to create windows firewall exception.  The following command gives Syntex Error.  Please advise where to make change.

Thanks

```
netsh firewall add allowedprogram C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Binn\ sqlservr.exe “SQL Server Windows NT” ENABLE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Vista/Win2008 or up do this:

all at one line, I added linebreaks here for readability:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule 
          name="SQL Server Windows NT" 
          dir=in 
          action=allow 
          program="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe " 
          enable=yes
```

the [kb-article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947709) detailing the new command.

Comment: Thanks you!  This statement asked to run as admin.  How to do it?
I want to run this command from a batch file from my vb.net application.

Comment: For that question you better start a new one or have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077685/automatically-running-a-program-as-administrator-in-vb-net). Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted.