# Modify windows firewall in a C program

Tags: c, windows, firewall

I have a server\client application written in C which requires me to open some ports and add applications to windows firewall on both ends. Currently i am doing it mannually  in order that my program will run.

I would like to create an installer for my program that will automatically add the ports and application to the firewall.

So my question is, is there a C library or CMD commands which i can use in order to modify the firewall on installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the command line, it is possible to use something like this to open ports:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="My Custom Rule In" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=9191

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="My Custom Rule Out" dir=out action=allow protocol=TCP localport=9191
```

And to add a rule to an application

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="SQL Server Windows NT" dir=inaction=allow program="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQLServer\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe " enable=yes
```

Example taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913010/creating-firewall-excetption-using-netsh-command)

On windows, you can use the system() command to spawn a netsh process passing the arguments needed.

Comment: You could make your c program start the netsh program passing the arguments you need on startup. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278641/how-can-i-run-an-external-program-in-c

Comment: yes thats what i am planning, how do i add an .exe to the in an out? i need  2 exe which are third party to be allowed in the firewall

Comment: Check this link, it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14913010/creating-firewall-excetption-using-netsh-command

Comment: Are dir=in and dir=out refer to inbound or outbound rules?